# how to set default language for facebook in webview for flutter_facebook_login plugin

Tags: flutter, facebook, facebook-graph-api, flutter-facebook-login

Im using flutter_facebook_login plugin https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_login

```
Future<Null> _facebookLogin() async {

facebookSignIn.loginBehavior = FacebookLoginBehavior.webViewOnly;
FacebookLoginResult result = await facebookSignIn.logIn([
  'email',
  'instagram_basic',
  'pages_show_list',
  'pages_read_engagement'
]);

switch (result.status) {
  case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
    accessToken = result.accessToken;
    _loginAsNewUser(accessToken.token);
    break;
  case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    _auth.signOut();

    break;
  case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
    simplestDialogBox(
        context, 'An error Occured! Please try after some time.', () {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    });
    _auth.signOut();
    await _logOut();
    break;
}
}
```

Here I'm using web View for login. So how to set default language as English for the login page?
I sometimes get Marathi, sometimes Hindi, which is local language. If i were to use use native view or browser, then the language will depend upon user preferences, but how to use default language EN in web View.

Comment: I don’t think that is actually possible. Facebook doesn’t let you force the login dialog language, but determines what language to use from the environment. Which makes sense to a certain extend, because just because I am trying out an app written by someone in, say, China or Russia, doesn’t mean I understand the respective languages.

Comment: thanks for reply, but in india, this feature is very annoying because most the users prefers english, but fb login page appears in native language, and because of so many native languages, sometimes it appears in the language of which user is not familiar to.